# SQL query to classify triangles into Equilateral, Isosceles, etc

Tags: sql, oracle

Please tell me what is wrong in this code? 
I'm getting 
"ERROR at line 2: 
ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis" for the following snippet. Please help me out.

```
select (
IF (A = B or B = C or C = A) THEN
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Isosceles')
ELSIF (A=B and B=c) THEN
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Equilateral')
ELSIF (A != B) and (B != C) and (A+B>C or B+C>A or A+C>B)THEN
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Scalene')
ELSE
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Not A Triangle')
END IF
)
from triangles;
```

Comment: Please explain what you're trying to do - your code is riddled with syntax errors...

Comment: Shouldn't all three sides being equal mean isosoles?  Not "or" - "and".

Comment: Noooo, you can't use `IF-ELSE` statement in Oracle query. Search for `CASE`. And you can't `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE` in a query, too.

Comment: Ok i'm sorry and thank you all. I'm learning a lot about SQL nowadays and you guys are certainly helpful. Will take into account your suggestions.

Comment: I'm basically trying out a challenge where we get to find out what type of triangle we're dealing with.

Comment: Q: What is wrong with this code?  A: It is not SQL.

Comment: I understand that my query may have been riddled with a lot of errors and i'll make sure that I research a hell of a lot more before I post any questions here on StackOverflow and will try my level best to not waste any of your time and energy on lame questions. But please dont downvote cos i'm not able to ask any question now on other topics as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep in mind that CASE statements are evaluated IN ORDER - the first WHEN clause that fits "wins" and no further evaluation is made. So:

```
with
     triangles ( A, B, C ) as (
       select 20, 20, 23 from dual union all
       select 20, 20, 20 from dual union all
       select 20, 21, 22 from dual union all
       select 13, 14, 30 from dual
     )
select A, B, C, 
       case
            when A+B <= C  or B+C <= A or C+A <= B then 'Not A Triangle'                
            when A    = B and B    = C             then 'Equilateral'
            when A    = B  or B    = C or A    = C then 'Isosceles'
            else                                        'Scalene'  
            end  as classification
from   triangles
;

  A   B   C   CLASSIFICATION
--- --- ---   --------------
 20  20  23   Isosceles
 20  20  20   Equilateral
 20  21  22   Scalene
 13  14  30   Not A Triangle

4 rows selected.
```

Comment: Thank you @mathguy

Comment: Now i'm using ur code but still output is wrong. i'm not sure why. The following is the challenge i'm trying: 
Maybe u can try it out if possible: 
https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/what-type-of-triangle

Comment: @Vish - "Output is wrong" doesn't say much. WHAT is wrong? Show us three numbers you put in, and what the result was, and then we can discuss if it is right or wrong.

Comment: It's on Hackerrank, so they don't show me the existing data. They just test our testcase and tell us if our code has passed or not. that's why i sent you the link.

Comment: Sorry, I won't join websites that are unknown (to me) just for that purpose. I see what they want there - perhaps you just need to capitalize `'Not A Triangle'`. I can also use their numbers into a test, I can actually add that to my answer.

Comment: @Vish - I updated the answer to include the examples from the web site. See above for why perhaps what you tried didn't work there.

Comment: Thanks @mathguy. it was seriously an issue of just capitalizing the t in Triangle. thanks again :)

Comment: This question may have been lame / stupid. I've gotten past this particular problem and I have other questions that I wish to ask but Stack overflow won't allow me to post questions cos of my previous lame questions which got negative votes. So how am I supposed to improve this question now? after a year?

Comment: Thank you for spending your valuable time and energy on my question @mathguy!

Comment: @gireesh4manu -  I wasn’t aware that you are not allowed to post more questions if you have old ones with downvotes, are you sure that is the reason? I would find it odd if it is.

Comment: Either it's a down vote or to be precise the quality of my questions were poor , that's what I found out from the help

Answer (score 0):

This code works for the HackerRank SQL challenge called Type of Triangle, just needed to remove A,B,C from the SELECT clause:

```
select 
      case
          when A+B <= C  or B+C <= A or C+A <= B then 'Not A Triangle'                
          when A    = B and B    = C             then 'Equilateral'
          when A    = B  or B    = C or A    = C then 'Isosceles'
          else                                        'Scalene'  
          end  as classification
from   triangles;
```

Answer (score 0):

The below query worked for me in MySQL

```
SELECT 
CASE 
    WHEN (A = B) AND (B = C) AND (A + B) > C THEN 'Equilateral'
    WHEN ((A = B AND A != C) OR (B = A AND B != C) OR (C = A AND C != B)) AND (A + B) > C THEN 'Isosceles'
    WHEN (A != B AND A != C) AND (B != A AND B != C) AND (C != A AND C != B) AND (A + B) > C THEN 'Scalene'
    ELSE 'Not A Triangle'
END AS RESULT FROM TRIANGLES;
```